# Locate element using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to locate "U10 Boys" text using Xpath on the basis of "2014 Spring Recreation Soccer" text from the following HTML structure:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td > </td>
                  <td >
                    <span>2014 Spring Recreation Soccer</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table >
      <tbody>
        <tr >
          <td >1</td>
          <td >
            <b>
              <span >U10 Boys</span>
            </b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried following Xpath, but it's not working.

```
//span[contains(text(), "U10 Boys")]//following-sibling::table/thead/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span[contains(text(), "2014 Spring Recreation Soccer")]
```

Comment: The quickest way I find, is to use Firebug (in Firefox), right click on an element and select 'copy as XPath'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this way :**

```
//div[table[contains(., "2014 Spring Recreation Soccer")]/following-sibling::div[1]//span[contains(.,"U10 Boys")]
```

**explanation :**

- `//div[table[contains(., "2014 Spring Recreation Soccer")]` : find `div` element, anywhere in the document, where child element `table` contains text `"2014 Spring Recreation Soccer"`
- `/following-sibling::div[1]` : from such `div`, navigate to the nearest following sibling `div` ...
- `//span[contains(.,"U10 Boys")]` : ... and return `span` element that contains text `"U10 Boys"` within the sibling `div`